# Facebook SDK for .NET - Search keywords in public posts

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to search for a specific keyword in public posts using facebook c# sdk, and then list all the results with the name of the user who posted it, time when it was posted and the post itself.

The problems I'm having is.. well.. I cannot wrap my head around the SDK really.

What I want is really simple, and I can achive what I want using:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelons&type=post

So my question is; 
Can this be done using the [Facebook SDK .NET?](http://facebooksdk.net/)

Or have I misunderstood the concept of the SDK completely?

I'm thankful for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I solved it - I'm not sure if it's a good solution at all...
But it seems to work:

```cs
            var client = new FacebookClient();
            string searchKeyword = keyWord;
            dynamic result = client.Get("/search?q=" + searchKeyword + "&type=post");
```

It works alright, but It's not very sexy.
I hope someone else will find it useful.